# OpenGL ES 2.0 - performance / optimalization needed?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing about 30 - 80 textured planes (squares) - backgrounds, player, enemies, bullets, etc.
All planes move and scale, some +rotate and some have animated textures.
I think, it can't be too hard for CPU or GPU, but on slower/older devices it has relative low performance - for example on Galaxy ACE.
Please, Can you look my code, what am I doing wrong or dirty? Or what can be optimalized?

Thank you.
This is my onSurfaceCreated, onSurfaceChanged and onDrawFrame:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) { 
  ..
  // load and prepare all textures 
  ..

  GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  
  GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);             
  GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);       
  GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            

  GLES20.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
  GLES20.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
  final float eyeX = 0.0f; final float eyeY = 0.0f; final float eyeZ = 1.5f;       
  final float lookX = 0.0f; final float lookY = 0.0f; final float lookZ = -3.0f;
  final float upX = 0.0f; final float upY = 1.0f; final float upZ = 0.0f;
  Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);  

  mProgramHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();    

  final String vertexShader =
  "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;         \n"                       
  + "attribute vec4 a_Position;      \n"                            
  + "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate; \n"    
  + "attribute float a_AlphaValue;   \n"
  + "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   \n"            
  + "varying float v_AlphaValue;     \n"
  + "void main()                     \n"                                
  + "{                               \n"                          
  + "   v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;      \n"  
  + "   v_AlphaValue = a_AlphaValue;            \n"
  + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position; \n"
  + "}                                          \n";        

  final String fragmentShader =
  "precision lowp float;                \n"         
  + "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;       \n"     
  + "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;      \n"     
  + "varying float v_AlphaValue;        \n"             
  + "void main()                        \n"     
  + "{                                  \n"
  + "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate); \n"             
  + "   gl_FragColor.a *= v_AlphaValue; \n"
  + "}                                  \n";            

  final int vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);     
  final int fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);       
  mProgramHandle = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, new String[] {"a_Position", "a_TexCoordinate", "a_AlphaValue"});

  GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);  
  mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
  mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVMatrix");
  mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position");
}   

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {    
  GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  float ratio = (float) width / height;
  Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 1000);
}   

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
  GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND); 
  GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  updateGame();

  // all planes are saved in Vector<Mesh> children          
  int size = children.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    children.get(i).Draw(renderer);
  }
}
```

And Draw(Renderer) in 'plane' object:

```
public void Draw(Renderer renderer)
{                       
  if (!Visible) return; // no visible object, no need draw
  mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(renderer.mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");
  GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mBrickDataHandle); 
  mAlphaHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(renderer.mProgramHandle, "a_AlphaValue");       
  GLES20.glVertexAttrib1f(mAlphaHandle, alpha);

  // texture animation
  renderer.mPlaneTextureCoords[(byte)indexAnim].position(0); 
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, renderer.mPlaneTextureCoords[(byte)indexAnim]);
  indexAnim++;

  renderer.mPlanePositions.position(0); 
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(Renderer.mPositionHandle, renderer.mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, renderer.mPlanePositions);        
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(Renderer.mPositionHandle);                       

  if (angleZ == 0) // no rotating plane -> no need setRotateM
  {
    Matrix.setIdentityM(renderer.mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(renderer.mModelMatrix, 0, x, y, z);
    Matrix.scaleM(renderer.mModelMatrix, 0, scaleX, scaleY, 1);
  }
  else // rotating plane
  {
    float[] mt = new float[16];
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mt, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mt, 0, x, y, z);
    Matrix.scaleM(mt, 0, scaleX, scaleY, 1);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotZMatrix, 0, angleZ, 0, 0, 1);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(renderer.mModelMatrix, 0, mt, 0, mRotZMatrix, 0);
  }

  Matrix.multiplyMM(renderer.mMVPMatrix, 0, renderer.mViewMatrix, 0, renderer.mModelMatrix, 0);   
  GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(renderer.mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, renderer.mMVPMatrix, 0);                

  //Matrix.multiplyMM(renderer.mMVPMatrix, 0, renderer.mProjectionMatrix, 0, renderer.mMVPMatrix, 0);
  Matrix.multiplyMM(renderer.mTemporaryMatrix, 0, renderer.mProjectionMatrix, 0, renderer.mMVPMatrix, 0); // little bit faster (?)
  System.arraycopy(renderer.mTemporaryMatrix, 0, renderer.mMVPMatrix, 0, 16);

  GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(renderer.mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, renderer.mMVPMatrix, 0); // pass in the combined matrix
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);        
  GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on a newer version of the Android SDK (e.g. v16) you can use the profiler to find out where the problem areas are:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

But at first glance there are a couple of things I can see:

1. Another responder highlighted that you are calling `glGetAttribLocation` inside your draw call, you don't need to do this every time you draw.  Once the "program" is set these references can be obtained and they won't change as long as that program doesn't change (i.e you don't change shaders).  Likewise with the calls to `glEnableVertexAttribArray`
2. Consider using a texture atlas.  Each call to `glBindTexture` may result in a state change in VRAM which is a slow operation.  A texture atlas is simply a single image which contains all (or many) or your textures (e.g. sprites).  When you specify the texture coordinates you simply specify a value between 0 and 1 representing the location of your single sprite within the atlas.  If you want to use this approach you will have to "bin pack" your atlas so you're not wasting space.  There are a few tools out there to do this (eg TexturePacker).  This means fewer (possibly only one) calls to `glBindTexture`
3. You're passing your MVP matrix twice with `glUniformMatrix4fv` which is unnecessary.  Changing the matrix that is sent to the shader after it's been sent will have no effect (i.e. the initial set operation will be overwritten) as the matrix is only used when the shader executes in the call to `glDrawArrays`
4. I have recently discovered that `setRotateM` is pretty damn slow.  There are alternatives around the place which I need to find also!
5. Your last `System.arrayCopy` is unnecessary.  You can just chain the matrix multiplication without needing the temp. matrix.  Model * View = MV, then  MV * Projection = MVP

If you haven't already you should also check out this tutorial:

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/

And if you DO decide to go down the route of a 3rd party game engine, IMO libgdx is by FAR the best:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

It's free, open source and has a strong focus on performance.  Having said that I too decided to build my own because I didn't need the breadth of features offered by libgdx but I have to say that every line of code I write makes me stop and question this decision ;)

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I fixed all errors/mistakes that you wrote, except point 2. - at least for now,
maybe it's too late to remake current project... so, I look for TexturePacker and i will consider this change :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to be calling glGet* so many times inside your draw loop, as it can be a slow operation.

Can you just cache the attribute locations locally inside the objects? Or I wonder why you are even setting attribute locations per-object at all for every object when they all use the same shader.

Comment: Thank you for reply. You are right... I fix it - now setting locations attributes inside onSurfaceCreated. It is faster now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a game engine before? Quite a few of them are able to handle this kind of task with quite a bit less code, and stress =P

It will take a bit more of your time initially to learn a game engine, but will save you hundreds of hours later on. Being designed for game, they usually handle a large amount of objects quite well without sacrificing performance, even on older devices.

This isn't a direct solution to your question but maybe it can help you later on ^.^
Here is a massive list of game engines for Android
http://mobilegameengines.com/android/game_engines

If you like Open Source Game Engines you might like these, I have only had experience using a few of these but I find AndEngine to be the simplest to get started on, and it is definitely powerful enough to handle 30-80 objects.
http://ntt.cc/2011/05/08/8-open-source-android-game-engines.html

Comment: Thank you for reply. So, I'm beginner and i'm learning it :-) I started with a simple 2D game. I think, I don't need game engine, at least for now, maybe with some next (more complicated) project :-)